# Why is my "shared" link getting sent to the wrong place?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering why my new "share" feature wasn't getting much use - and now I think I've found out why.

Using FB's debug tool for OpenGraph:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

..with the following URL:

https://steampunkjunkies.net/competitions/win-one-of-these-necklaces-5.html

[image]

As you can see, its got a **Canonical URL** and **Final URL**. I'm a bit baffled as to where these 2 values have come from though - as when I run a `lynx` command in a local SSH client, it works perfectly (and shows the page it's meant to)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not really an "answer" as such - but its fixed my issue:

1. Graph was moaning about me not having an **og:description** set - so I've fixed that up
2. I changed my URL format from https://steampunkjunkies.net/competitions/win-one-of-these-necklaces-5.html?ref=unique_code, to https://steampunkjunkies.net/competitions/unique_code/win-one-of-these-necklaces-5.html

These 2 tweaks, seem to have appeased Facebook!